# How to reload whole svg after click a button without reload page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, svg, jquery-svg

https://github.com/a115/HTML-SVG-connect I am using this plugin for draw draggable line. But this plugin don't give me the permission to recreate line after load svg. I want create line when click on two element.

Comment: Please add some code to your question which you have tried so far.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/alojzije/11127839

Comment: Can anyone help me ! How can I reinitialise svg without reload page. On click event or etc ?

Answer (score 0):

```
/*css*/
svg {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Solved! I have used this css for freeze svg and lines.

Comment: sorry! but this is not different answers I just "append" svg into div after some time so it automatically append one by one. So I fixed it by css with {position: absolute;}.

Comment: You have two separate answers to this question. Why is that?

Answer (score -1):

```
    addSvgInHere = function(_this, $element, $svg, defs, markerObjCircleS, circleObjS, markerObj, arrowObj) {
  timerId = setInterval(function(argument) {
    $element.append($svg);
              if ( $(_this).attr('data-trigger') != "true") { 
                $(defs).appendTo($svg);                        
                }       

              },500);
    setInterval(function (argument) {
                markerObjCircleS.appendChild(circleObjS);
                markerObj.appendChild(arrowObj);
                $(defs).append(markerObjCircleS);
                $(defs).append(markerObj);         
    },1000);
};
```